# Using node/vuejs, how to make google place API request on client side

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-places-api

I am using vuejs which runs as a single page application in the browser, so any API calls I am making are using axios. Unfortunately googles APIs block any requests through axios due to CORS. I have tried various npm packages to try and solve this, including "official" [google maps package](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js), but I still run into CORS issues.

I am positive there must be a way to do a placeid search through the browser using one of their javascript libraries, but I can't for the life of me find any good articles or examples to see how it is done.

I have google autocomplete working, and creating google maps through geocode is no problem, just can't find anything related to placeid search.

Here is an example of the request I am trying to make taken from googles docs.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Can anyone provide a solution or link to an explanation on how to do this properly through javascript library, or through API call without running into CORS problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link to Google Maps Package is Node.js package (server side). That's why you have CORS issue.

> If you're building a client-side application, take a look at the
>   [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro), the [Places SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro), and the [Places
>   Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

If you want to use it Google Maps on client side, you should use [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: Where does google actually show how to use their library though? They provide a script to include but I can't find any actual examples that are doing a placeid search. The only examples I find are google maps, directions, etc.

Comment: I might end up feeling stupid very soon, I think I have found the documentation digging deeper into the Places Library link you provided. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places.